# Conditionally sorting for an even distribution of records

Tags: laravel, sorting, eloquent, laravel-8

Suppose I have 10 Eloquent model records in an `Item` model such as this (represented as JSON for simplicity):

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'Item 1', featured: false},
  {id: 2, name: 'Item 2', featured: true},
  {id: 3, name: 'Item 3', featured: false},
  {id: 4, name: 'Item 4', featured: false},
  {id: 5, name: 'Item 5', featured: false},
  {id: 6, name: 'Item 6', featured: false},
  {id: 7, name: 'Item 7', featured: true},
  {id: 8, name: 'Item 8', featured: false},
  {id: 9, name: 'Item 9', featured: false},
  {id: 10, name: 'Item 10', featured: true},
]
```

I want to organize this list first by `id` ascending then distributing the records such that every two records where `featured = false` is followed by one record where `featured = true`.

The result would look like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'Item 1', featured: false},
  {id: 3, name: 'Item 3', featured: false},
  {id: 2, name: 'Item 2', featured: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Item 4', featured: false},
  {id: 5, name: 'Item 5', featured: false},
  {id: 7, name: 'Item 7', featured: true},
  {id: 6, name: 'Item 6', featured: false},
  {id: 8, name: 'Item 8', featured: false},
  {id: 10, name: 'Item 10', featured: true},
  {id: 9, name: 'Item 9', featured: false},
]
```

How would I do this using an Eloquent collection or query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working solution using collections (I'm sure it can be cleaned up quite a bit):

```
$result = collect($items)->sortBy('id')->partition(function ($i) {
  return $i['featured'];
})->pipe(function ($groups) {
   return $groups->last()->chunk(2)->reduce(function ($carry, $item) use ($groups) {
      $item->each(function ($i) use ($carry) {
         $carry->push($i);
      });
      
      if ($groups->first()->isNotEmpty()) {
         $carry->push($groups->first()->shift());
      }

      return $carry;
   }, collect());
});
```

See it in action [here](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/aca599ad-f07d-4b81-84c5-4b7f086ca68f).